# Dance Dance Revolution Game

Tags: vb.net

http://i44.tinypic.com/znlvra.png

So I got this game like dance dance revo it wors Ok it says good and perfect when you hit an arrow i got a problem with the perfect hit it works depends on the speed on the arrows but I got an option easy, medium and hard basically easy is the slowest and hard is the fastest in the medium speed it I never ever hit a perfect so I'm asking if you guys have a better method to get the perfect or help me improve this code:

```
'Perfect Hit
If (RArrowDown.Top = ArrowDown.Top) And RArrowDown.Visible = True Then
    TimerMain.Enabled = False
    Hit += 1
    Score += 20
    RArrowDown.Visible = False
    Perfect.Visible = True
    TimerPerfect.Enabled = True
    Combo_Counter += 1
    RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
    'End If
    'Good Hit
ElseIf (RArrowDown.Top <= ArrowDown.Top + ArrowDown.Height) And (ArrowDown.Top <= RArrowDown.Top + RArrowDown.Height) And RArrowDown.Visible = True Then
    TimerMain.Enabled = False
    Hit += 1
    Score += 10
    RArrowDown.Visible = False
    Good.Visible = True
    TimerGood.Enabled = True
    Combo_Counter += 1
    RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way is to get a value indicating how far off from perfect the keypress is (I think it is very unliekly that someone actually gets it perfectly), then act on this value. You can then tweak the bands that give you a perfect or good hit:

```
Dim offset as Integer
If [Right Arrow Pressed]
    offset = RarrowDown.Top - ArrowDown.Top
End If

Select Case offset

case is 0 to 3
    'perfect

case 4 to 10
    'good

case 11 to 20
    'poor

case else
    'missed

End Select
```